# Using C# to do xslt transform ignoring xsl:output

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am doing an xslt transform inside my c# program. When I run the xslt on its own it outputs just fine, but when I run it from within my c# program it always leaves off the:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

At the top of the resulting xml document. My XSLT file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:hd="http://www.hotdocs.com/schemas/component_library/2009"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/xsd:schema">
     <hd:componentLibrary xmlns:hd="something" version="10">
     </hd:componentLibrary>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am running the xslt in my c# program like this:

```
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(PathToXMLDocument);
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(PathToXSLTDocument);
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(PathToOutputLocation, null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc,null,myWriter);
myWriter.Close();
```

I have tried the xslt document without the xsl:output line, but that does not seem to help.

How can i get the ?xml tag at the top of my outputted xml file?

Thanks

Comment: `new XmlTextWriter` -- that's so 2003! Are you stuck with .NET Framework 1.1?

Comment: Ha, not quite. Stuck using .NET 2.0 sp2 though. Also using VS 2005 (not sure if that is relevant). Decided to use XmlTextWriter from a quick google search. Is there a better option? Do tell!

Comment: [XmlWriter.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create\(v=VS.80\).aspx)

Comment: That actually fixed the issue! Always smart to use modern classes. If you want to make a full answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Why is this an issue, in any case where `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is the correct declaration it can be omitted anyway.

Comment: I am creating an "answer" file for a program called HotDocs. If that line is omitted the "answer" file is not accepted. After some playing around with the file I realized that HotDocs needs that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlTextWriter is a bit outdated. I recommend you switch to [XmlWriter.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create.aspx).

Then you can specify [OmitXmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration.aspx)  = false in the [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [XmlWriter.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162617.aspx) then you can pass an [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) instance as a parameter. The [OmitXmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration.aspx) member in the settings class controls whether or not the  tag is included.